# Mass update of records in CouchDB

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I have an employees database in CouchDB that has over 100k of records. I need to update the salary field for all of them. I am using nodejs and cradle and would the code below be the right way to go ? Are there any other alternatives if this is not good practice ?

```
var newsalary;
db.view('myviews/employees', function (err, res) {
res.forEach(function (row) {
    newsalary=row.salary+5;
    db.merge(row._id, {salary: newsalary},function (err, res) {}); // update self here
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried saving multiple rows at once? I haven't work with cradle, but seems like it supports db.save with array input. So, you may try doing save in batch(like 100/1000 records at a time). Otherwise, as of current implementation, it will interact with db everytime for each record, which is bad in term of both time and db load.